# Parallel processing data analysis - Is there a benefit to having more splits than processor cores?

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, parallel-foreach

I am using a naive Bayesian classifier to predict some test data in R. The test data has >1,000,000,000 records, and takes far too long to process with one processor. The computer I am using has (only) four processors in total, three of which I can free-up to run my task (I could use all four, but prefer to keep one for other work I need to do).

Using the `foreach` and `doSNOW` packages, and following [this](https://www.r-bloggers.com/parallel-r-model-prediction-building-and-analytics/) tutorial, I have things set up and running. My question is:

*I have the dataset split into three parts, one part per processor. Is there a benefit to splitting the dataset into say 6,9, or 12 parts? In other words, what is the trade-off between more splits, vs, just having one big block of records for each processor core to run?*

I haven't provided any data here because I think this question is more theoretical. But if data are needed, please let me know.

Comment: I think most people will say more splits hurt. In general, approaching infinite splits is hurtful. (I think this is obvious to most people). But I also found that more splits (within a reasonable number) can be helpful sometimes. Case: 'load' of operations is difficult to predict/balance. I sometimes have operations that depending on the entry values (but with the same # of entries) will take 2-5x longer. This means that I'm sometimes waiting 2-5x longer for a single worker to finish when others  are done. With more splits, you can divide the difficult-to-operate-on splits across more cores.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm on a fairly limited machine, without access to cloud computing, so looking for alternatives to this fairly large task.

Comment: FYI to close vote queue:  I don't think this question is too broad for Stackoverflow.  Even though it doesn't include any code, it does highlight a useful aspect of this kind of large-dataset analysis with parallel processing.  I voted to leave it open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Broadly speaking, the advantage of splitting it up into more parts is that you can optimize your processor use.

If the dataset is split into 3 parts, one per processor, and they take the following time:

Split A - 10 min

Split B - 20 min

Split C - 12 min

You can see immediately that two of your processors are going to be idle for a significant amount of time needed to do the full analysis.

Instead, if you have 12 splits, each one taking between 3 and 6 minutes to run, then processor A can pick up another chunk of the job after it finishes with the first one instead of idling until the longest-running split finishes.

Comment: I'm fairly ignorant in the ways of parallel processing. Is there a reason to think the processors will have vastly different completion times, if they are each given an equal size chunk of data to process, with the same instructions per chunk?

Comment: That depends on your data, the nature of your algorithm, and the details of your implementation :)  If your data records are all independent of each other, there's no special reason to expect *large* timing differences between parts.  OTOH, if there's anything in there that can trigger extra steps in your algorithm in a non-uniform fashion, that could give you those timing differences.  Another caveat is that more splits adds more "housekeeping" time to the job.  Without measurements, you'd have to rely on intuition about the type of problem you're doing.  Failing that, ... guesswork.

Comment: Thanks @Brian I think your answer and comments have pretty much answered my initial question. Appreciate your time.

Comment: Good luck with your analysis :)

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. I have been wondering for some time if there is an optimal set of splits you could use in order to have not too many but to get some space for not idling. I think I tried once to use N * (N +1) / 2 splits for N cores. But I think it should also depends on the size of what you split. Any thought?

Comment: @F.Privé I agree that it depends on the size of your data set.  There are a lot of examples where splitting it at all actually increases the processing time because of the overhead of parallelization.  I'm not aware of any "rules of thumb" for optimal splits; it varies too much depending on your particular data and algorithm.